# Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to solve this error

Failed to compile
./node_modules/@selderee/plugin-htmlparser2/lib/hp2-builder.mjs
Attempted import error: 'Picker' is not exported from 'selderee'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.